# TFS 2010 - command line for convert to branch

Tags: tfs, branch

TFS exposes a commmand line utility which covers most of the areas.
However I am creating a script which will create the folder and branch structure within a specified project.

For this i need to convert my Truck to a branch and then further create branches from there.
I cannot find the command which does this.

So far I have found this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx) which desribes to to convert a folder to a brnch, but has no reference to the command line utility unlike the other descriptions.

Does that mean that the command line utility does not support this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is answered in more detail on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2577fc05-8745-447c-941b-f4fc1cdae09a/convert-folder-to-branch-via-commandline?forum=tfspowertools)

TL;DR

You can use the `tfpt branches /convertToBranch` from the [power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/)