# Convert all branches in TFS 2010 hiearchy to Folders

Tags: tfs

We recently upgraded from TFS 2008 to 2010.  The upgrader attempts to "guess" which folders should be branches, and which should be branched folders.  We had some cases in our structure where we had nested branches, and the upgrader guessed incorrectly.

I would like to reset some hiearchies of branches back to "branched folders" status, and then manually apply the "Convert to Branch" operation in the appropriate locations.  However, it's really tedious to navigate through the menues for every folder, and select "convert to folder" (there are a lot of them).

So, is there a way to do this in a batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a batch or a powershell script using the tfpt tool from [TFS Powertools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801539/tfs-2010-command-line-for-convert-to-branch).