# TF.exe creates folder instead of branch

Tags: c#, tfs, tf-cli

I use tf.exe in my C# code to create new branches in TFS. This is what I do:

```
public static bool TFBranch(string projectPath, string originName, string branchName)
{
    string branchedProject = projectPath + "\\" + branchName;

    string projectToBranch = projectPath + "\\" + originName;

    string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"branch " + projectToBranch + " " + branchedProject);
    path = path.Replace("\\", "/");

    return ExecuteProcess(path);
}

private static bool ExecuteProcess(string path)
{
    MyProcess proc = new MyProcess();

    var currentDirectory = WorkspaceHandler.GetLocalWorkspace();

    var command = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe";

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDirectory);
    proc.FileName = command;
    proc.Arguments = path;

    try
    {
        proc.Execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _Logger.Error("Could not execute TF.exe. Exception: " + e.ToString());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Mostly everything works as I except it. I branch from an directory that already contains a branch, so the new branch contains also a branch. But sometimes tf.exe creates a folder, not a branch. Is this a bug from tf.exe, or am I doing anything wrong?

Example:

This is how an branch command can look like:

[image]

[image]

**-- EDIT --**

Here is how I do it manually:

1. I use the menu to branch Templates/BranchSource/Folder/Main:

[image]

2. In the dialog I define the "Target Branch Name":

[image]

3. The result is what I expected to get:

[image]

This is the same result that I get when I do it with my code. The only difference is that the code creates a folder sometimes.

Comment: Do you test with tf branch command manually? I've tested with TFS 2013.5+VS2013.5, tf branch command only can create folder icon, not branch icon.

Comment: I tried that too. Wheter I try it manually or with my code it always creates a branch icon. Just sometimes it creates a folder and I can not reconstruct this behavior. I just seems to happen randomly.

Comment: Do you have the same environment as mine? I always get folder icon on my side.

Comment: Yes I also use TFS 2013 and VS 2013 Update 5.

Comment: I just added what I exactly do, when I do it "manually".

Comment: How about use tf branch command manually? Not from the UI. From UI, you do can get a branch icon.

Comment: Do you mean with command prompt? That causes the same result.

Comment: With command https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/tfvc/branch-command, I can only get folder icon.

Comment: Yes thats excatly what I use to branch. Thats also what I use in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.exe` can't do that, but you can do it with the tfpt.exe from the power tools after the branch had been created. (or from the Source control explorer in Visual Studio):

```
tfpt branches /convertToBranch
```

See also:

- [TFS 2010 - command line for convert to branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801539/tfs-2010-command-line-for-convert-to-branch/3803159#3803159)

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about converting the folder to branch after branching, but that seems very dirty to me. I mean, if it works the first time, then it should also work twice. If I do it a third time tf.exe creates a branch as I expect it again.

Comment: I don't think that tf.exe tries anything special it just calls the CreateBranch function on he server and waits for the result.

Comment: I think so too. But when I branch manually from a folder that is already converted to a branch, the new folder also should be a branch too. Or am I wrong? As you can see in my example I branch from Templates/BranchSource/Folder/Main and Main is already a branch. If I am right then the Main folder from SecondBranchedFolder/Folder/Main should also be a branch and no folder.

Comment: Not that I know of. From the UI the checkbox gets enabled by default I believe, from the commandline there is no such checkbox.

Comment: Yes there is no checkbox. But as I said in the question, my code works fine. From about nine of ten times the branch is branched as I expect it. As you can see in FirstBranchedFoler/Folder/Main. This was created by my code which uses TF.exe. Whithout any kind of checkbox. But sometimes and it seems to be very randomely, it doesent work as I wish to. I just want to know why it sometimes creates a branch and sometimes a folder.

Comment: It´s not what I originally wanted, but it soloves my problem. There are no branches as folders anymore. If anyone has an idea why tf.exe generates sometimes folders and sometimes branches, you are welcome to let me know :) !